# Rails External API Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm writing tests for my Rails app. My app communicates with an external API that processes customer payments, specifically BrainTree. Now, I want to make sure my app's class that communicates with BrainTree works properly e.g. that it submits user information and other parameters to BrainTree correctly. Making the goal to only test that BrainTree and my App are communicating properly.

One thing to note, is that BrainTree has a sandbox account. To test my class, should I:

- Write a feature test using something like Capybara and Rspec and test it from a user's perspective e.g. user logs in, fills out form, submits payment etc.
- Write a request spec that just submits the required information and examines the return values. This is what I would prefer but is tricky since BrainTree requires js, and I am not sure I can do have js in a request spec without monkey patching Rspec, which I'd rather not do since I am still fairly new to Rspec and testing in general.
- Write both feature and request specs
- Write a completely different type of test

I have a feature test in place, but it seems cumbersome to use to just test an external API since it needs to open a browser, fill out forms, etc. in my feature spec I'd rather stub the external API and test the API as a unit test. A request spec seems more efficient but the js requirement seems like a roadblock.

Is there a Best Practice to what I should do in my scenario above?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you don't typically want to write tests only for an external service, but instead for your own code that tests against the responses you receive.

The best way I've found to stub a response from an external API is the [VCR gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr). This will get a legitimate response and save it for use in future runs. You can erase the stored response occasionally to ensure continued functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why is it typical to not write against an external API? For instance, I’m testing the external API because the 3rd party needs to save certain data based on certain options that I send it. The main reason I’m writing the test is to ensure that the 3rd party is saving the data correctly.

Comment: @Darkisa whether the 3rd party saves the data correctly is outside your control and therefore it wouldn't be ideal for you to test their functionality. Rather you want to test the contract they give to you, their API request/response and ensure that you handle any cases accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to testing this is to use a fake service that mimics the API. [Fake Braintree Gem](https://github.com/highfidelity/fake_braintree) provides such functionality and I've used this with a mix of VCR for other tests to ensure correct functionality. There's many other approaches but you can test to see which one fits your needs